# Swift 5 tableview image, textLabel, and disclosure indicator placement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView displayed programmatically.

Currently, the imageView, textLabel, and disclosure indicator are all **centered** in the cell like so:

[image]

I would like the imageView, textLabel, and disclosure indicator to be moved to the **bottom** of the cell next to the cell separator line while still being centered(marked in red box).

Essentially, leaving more **white space above** the image, text, and disclosure.

How can I accomplish this programmatically?

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    }
    
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Take a quick survey"
    cell?.imageView?.image =  resizeImageWithAspect(image: UIImage(named: cellImages[indexPath.row])!, scaledToMaxWidth: 30.0, maxHeight: 30.0)
    cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      
    return 100
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean as "moved to the bottom" and  "leaving more white space above" seems to conflict with being "centered". I think you can easily move the text/image lower down by just padding the tops. But you would need to make your own disclosure indicator as I think the default one is always rendered vertically  centered in the cell.

Comment: So no matter what system indicators cannot be moved from center?

Comment: It's not advisable to try and manipulate the layout of a "built-in style" cell. Much better off creating your own custom cell.